# Does it possible to make always getting update from database without refresh

Tags: php, database, web, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 as my framework. Currently working with API mobile, in which I plan to make the data to be always update concurrent with the database.

What should I do in order to make it work concurrently with the data in the database, example if there change on database through website then the API will get it.

I am just concern if there is a way that user can get the data even though while they are using the apps. mean without refresh, do I need to do it on UI site to get the data.

Does it same as Asynchronous?

Comment: Your API not going to get the latest data from database?

Comment: Every time the API is call the data will get the latest. What I am trying to do is if while the user is using the Data, if there is any change on database, the user will straight forward get the data

Comment: There's no automatic way to be notified when a database update happens. You'll need to poll periodically.

Comment: poll periodically really mean is?

Comment: You need a **real-time-updator** like [socket-io](https://socket.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check laravel [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting)

This is a websocket implementation, with this you can send a message to the client to notify something changes on the server. With this you can update the user interface with the new data from the database